# Android Studio - Java - API

Tags: java, android

Im using OkHttpClient to connect to an API.

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(BPI_ENDPOINT)
        .build();

okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Error during BPI loading : "
                + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
            throws IOException {
       final String body = response.body().string();

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                parseBpiResponse(body);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The `parseBpiResponse` just displays the data in `TextView` but the data request from the site takes place only once and in order to get the data again I need to either reopoen the activity or implement a button or swipe-screen etc,

How to call an API request constantly so that the data keeps updating instead of doing it through users input??

Answer (score 0):

you can use Timer class to do a network call periodically

```
final long period = 0;
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // do your task here
}
}, 0, period);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code but you should be careful about your activity and views in this code it my lead to nasty exception and memory leaks better thing to do is using live data with Recursion function !

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Checks the life cycle of the activity and if activity was destroyed break the while loop and exits 
            while (true && getLifecycle().getCurrentState() != Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
                okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Error during BPI loading : "
                                + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
                            throws IOException {
                        final String body = response.body().string();

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (getLifecycle().getCurrentState() != Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED)
                                    parseBpiResponse(body);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                try {
                    //Waits for 1 sec
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a recursive call .for example :

```
public void callAPI()
    {
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Error during BPI loading : "
                        + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
                    throws IOException {
                final String body = response.body().string();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        parseBpiResponse(body);
                    }
                });
         **//just use handler/timer or thread to post event after some interval**
                new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        callAPI();
                    }
                },2000);
            }
        });

    }
```

Also i suggest using `Rxjava+Retrofit` with `OkHttp` and use `interval` function to make it easier .